# Dask: Add list to a column value like pandas does

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dask, dask-distributed

I am bit new to dask. I have large csv file and large list. Length of row of csv are equal to length of the list. I am trying to create a new column in the Dask dataframe from a list. In pandas, it pretty straight forward, however in Dask I am having hard time creating new column for it. I am avoiding to use pandas because my data is 15GB+.

Please see my tries below.

### csv Data

```
name,text,address
john,some text here,MD
tim,some text here too,WA
```

### Code tried

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import numpy as np

ls = ['one','two']

ddf = dd.read_csv('../data/test.csv')
ddf.head()

Try #1: 
ddf['new'] = ls # TypeError: Column assignment doesn't support type list

Try #2: What should be passed here for condlist?
ddf['new'] = np.select(choicelist=ls) # TypeError: _select_dispatcher() missing 1 required positional argument: 'condlist'
```

### Looking for this output:

```
   name                text address new
0  john      some text here      MD one
1   tim  some text here too      WA two
```

Comment: does test.csv have only 2 rows? You need to create the list as a dask.array. `dd.from_array()` or `dd.from_pandas()`

Comment: I haven't installed dask yet... just reading about it so far. maybe you can try `ddf['new'] = np.array(ls)`

Answer (score 2):

Try creating a dask `dataframe` and then appending it like this -

```
#ls = dd.from_array(np.array(['one','two']))
#ddf['new'] = ls

# As tested by OP

import dask.array as da 
ls = da.array(['one','two','three'])
ddf['new'] = ls
```

Comment: I tried both `from_array` and `from_pandas` both gave me `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'ndim'`

Comment: The updated code didn't work however, it got me thinking about dask array. Here is how I fixed it: `import dask.array as da` and `ls = da.array(['one','two','three'])`

Comment: @Akshay Sehgal - did you run this answer successfully or is this a guess?

Comment: Ran it successfully

Comment: Ran it; This is the example in the official documentation Dask as well @HashRocketSyntax

Comment: Technically they are the same code. It may be an import error or something , updated with the other method as well.